# Flip a LINQ object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ object and i want to be able to flip it so that instead of the hierarchy Orders -> Articles -> Labels, i get Articles -> Labels -> Orders.

This simply means that i get an Article, and all its underlying labels. Then i check which ORDERS does this article belong to, then i add them as a collection.

```
var result = await _unitOfWork.Repository<OrderGroups>().FindByIncludeAsync(
               x => GroupIdsClaim.Contains(x.GroupId), b => 
               b.Include(v => v.Order)
                    .ThenInclude(h => h.OrderArticles)
                    .ThenInclude(t => t.Article)
                    .ThenInclude(q => q.LabelArticles)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Label));

var orderArticlesLabels = result.Select(x => new
{
    x.OrderId,
    x.Order.OrderNumber,
    Articles = x.Order.OrderArticles.Select(v => new
    {
        v.ArticleId,
        v.Article.Name,
        Labels = v.Article.LabelArticles.Select(k => new
        {
            k.LabelId,
            k.Label.Name
         })
    })
});
```

I expect the output of

```
  {
    "articleId" = xx,
    "name" = "yyy"
    "labels" : [],
    "orders" : []
  }
```

But am getting

`````
[
  {
    "orderId": 1,
    "orderNumber": "42253",
    "articles": [
      {
        "articleId": 4,
        "name": "Truck",
        "labels": [{"labelId": 1, "name": "label1"}]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": 2,
    "orderNumber": "42254",
    "articles": [{
        "articleId": 4,
         "name": "Truck",
        "labels": [{"labelId": 1, "name": "label1"}]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "orderId": 3,
    "orderNumber": "42255",
    "articles": [
      {
        "articleId": 2,
        "name": "Roads",
        "labels": [{"labelId": 1,"name": "label1"}]
      },
      {
        "articleId": 4,
        "name": "Truck",
        "labels": [{"labelId": 1,"name": "label1"}]
      }
    ]
  }]
````
`````

Comment: Sounds like you want `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: well, i think its in the same neighbourhood. How would i accomplish it on such an object.

Comment: You seem to be getting exactly what you're selecting, though.

Comment: well, i want to flip it over so that i get articles, all the orders the same article belongs to and the labels.

Comment: What is `resp`? What is `result`?

Comment: Please search online for what a DTO is. Basically it is a custom object that meets such requirements.

Comment: @CodingYoshi To create a DTO one must query the data first. He is trying to query above

Comment: @AvinKavish It was some typo. I changed resp to result

Comment: @HakimMarley, don't you have access to a articles repository? If you start the navigation from Articles, it would be much easier.

Comment: @AvinKavish Well, am using a generic repository for all the models. However, i have a many-to-many relationship between Orders and Articles, m-2-m between Articles and Labels. Another Entity that is not in the picture quite clearly is m-2-m between Orders and groups. Thats why i started from that entity because a user belongs to one or more groups and viceversa

Comment: @avinkavish You should change your handle to CaptainObvious.

Comment: What is the relation between Orders and Groups? 1-2-m ?

Comment: @AvinKavish, its not included in the Query. The reason why the generic repo starts from _unitOfWork.Repository<OrderGroups>() is because there, i get to query which group the current user belongs to, and which orders are connected to it, then i drill down the relationships

Comment: hmmm... that doesn't allow you to get the data you want, you should start at the article and have a where clause to filter by group.

Comment: I think thats whats missing too coz i have no relationship between articles and groups. I thought i would go via Orders, since they had a relationship with articles already

Comment: You have not posted your entity model so it is hard to infer the relationships between them from the question. But it should be as simple as: `var query = from a in ctx.Article join o in ctx.Order on a.OrderId equals o.OrderId join l in ctx.Label on a.LabelId equals l.LabelId select new { a.ArticleId // other stuff }; var result = query.ToList();` You now have a flat list of anonymous objects. Loop through them and create the DTO that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on client-side relationship fixups to achieve this. That imposes severe limitations such as an inability to paginate or filter results. The general rule is to start navigating the relationship at the primary entity you would like to retrieve. In this case that would be Articles.

```
var result = await dbContext.Articles.Where(a => 
                     a.OrderArticles.Any(oa => 
                       oa.Order.OrderGroups.Any(og => GroupIdsClaim.Contains(og.GroupId))))
                  .Include(a => a.LabelArticles)
                  .ThenInclude(la => la.Label)
                  .Select(a => new {
                      ArticleId = a.Id,
                      a.Name
                      Labels = a.LabelArticles.Select(la => la.Label)
                      Orders = a.OrderArticles.Select(oa => oa.Order)         
                  }).Skip().Take().DoAnythingYouWant().ToListAsync();
```

Note: I cannot guarantee that this will translate to efficient SQL or whether it will translate at all. This could even lead to n + 1 queries.  If it does, you can start navigating closer GroupIds, and perform a select through a different entity to get articles.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve this :

```
   {
    "articleId" = xx,
    "name" = "yyy"
    "labels" : [],
    "orders" : []
   }
```

then why don't you use DTO?

```
public class SomeDTO
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<LabelArticles> Labels { get; set; }
    public List<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
}

var orderArticlesLabels = result.Select(x => new SomeDTO()
{     

     x.Order.OrderArticles.Select(v => new
     {
       ArticleId = v.ArticleId,
       Name = v.Article.Name,
       Labels = v.Article.LabelArticles.Select(k => new
        {
           LabelId= k.LabelId,
           Name= k.Label.Name
         }),             
        Orders = new List<Order>() {new Order() {Id = x.Order.Id,OrderNumber=x.Order.OrderNumber }}
    })
});
```

Comment: 1. Orders and Articles is m-2-m. This adds just one order to order list. 2. This is nesting the DTO inside an anonymous class. I'm certain this does not compile.